# Full outer join of two ordered observables

Tags: join, rx-java, rx-java2

Suppose we have two observables `Observable<Integer> o1` and `Observable<Integer> o2` and each observable is producing strictly increasing sequence.

The task is to perform equivalent of full outer join on these two observables. For example join of

```
    Observable.just(0, 2, 3, 6)
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

should produce

```
    [ [0, _], [_, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [_, 4], [_, 5], [6, 6] ]
```

The join should be efficient and work well on very large or infinite streams.

The solution is easy in pull scenario. Is there an idiomatic rx way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single operator for this but it is possible to compose the behavior from standard and extension operators:

```
static abstract class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> { 
    int value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return Integer.compare(value, o.value);
    }
}

static final class Left extends Pair {
    Left(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + value + ", _]";
    }
}

static final class Right extends Pair {
    Right(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[_, " + value + "]";
    }
}

static final class Both extends Pair {
    Both(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Both) {
            return ((Both)obj).value == value;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + value + ", " + value + "]";
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void test() {
    Flowable<Integer> a = Flowable.just(0, 2, 3, 6);
    Flowable<Integer> b = Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    Flowable.defer(() -> {
        boolean[] skip = { false };
        return Flowables.<Pair>orderedMerge(
                a.<Pair>map(Left::new), b.<Pair>map(Right::new)
            )
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .buffer(2, 1)
            .flatMapIterable(buf -> {
                if (skip[0]) {
                    skip[0] = false;
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                if (buf.size() == 2) {
                    if (buf.get(0).value == buf.get(1).value) {
                        skip[0] = true;
                        return Collections.singletonList(new Both(buf.get(0).value));
                    }
                    return buf.subList(0, 1);
                }
                return buf;
            });
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

where `Flowables.orderedMerge` is in the [RxJava 2 Extensions library](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#rxjava2extensions).

Comment: Thanks, great answer, it works. 
Couple of questions/notes

1) distinctUntilChanged is only needed if there are duplicates is source observables, but if integers are strictly increasing that operation is redundant

2) `flatMapIterable` is supposed to be non respecting order and can be executed concurrently, isn't it? So, there seems to be a race due to usage of skip array. Should it not be replaced by `concatMapIterable`?

Thanks again.

Comment: 1) Yes. I left it there just in case. 2) No, consuming an Iterable is synchronous, doesn't allow for concurrent merging and is equivalent to `concatMapIterable`. In fact, they are the alias for the same underlying operator. Also the function is guaranteed to be executed sequentially thus the skip state from previous run will never be concurrently modified.