# Left outer join two sorted sparse sequences with project-reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Given two sorted streams of entities with sparse IDs. Let's model them as:

```
Flux<Long> stream1 = Flux.fromArray(new Long[] {1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L});
Flux<Long> stream2 = Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L));
```

Implement a function that composes a pipeline that does what in SQL is called FULL OUTER JOIN. So that in the end calling the following code:

```
public static Flux<Map.Entry<Long, Long>> fullOuterJoin(Flux<Long> stream1, Flux<Long> stream2) {
}
fullOuterJoin(stream1, stream2).log().subscribe();
```

Produces a result similar to the following:

```
onSubscribe(...)
request(...)
onNext(1=1)
onNext(null=2)
onNext(3=3)
onNext(4=4)
onNext(5=null)
onNext(6=6)
onNext(null=7)
onComplete()
```

Don't know if .join() could be used, tried .zip() but it does not map them by IDs and stops when the first of sequences runs out of elements. I know .bufferUntil() could be used but is looking for some other options, preferably some native support that I'm missing. Any ideas of how to implement it efficiently are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a straightforward fit for Reactive Streams, since nulls are not allowed in RS and there is no notion of a "sparse sequence". Trying to shoehorn a SQL/Set Theory concept into RS is not a guaranteed success :(

There is an answer in RxJava but it requires an operator from an extension, which we don't yet have in Reactor:

- [Full outer join of two ordered observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220837/full-outer-join-of-two-ordered-observables)
- https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/963